# HTML, CSS: How do I display the image in the whole div without any content

Tags: html, css

Hey there I am building a website! I'm trying to make the `background-image` to fit the whole `div.section`. I tried `height: 100%; width: 100%;` but it did not work. I need some help.

The part of the code which needs to have the background image:

```
.section {
  background: url("http://i.imgsafe.org/50f3f94.jpeg") no-repeat center/cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

My complete code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqxqw10/ (Make sure to make the width of the result maximum) or another link: https://mahalakshmi-consultants-shreyas1703.c9users.io/index.html

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Your `.section` element has no height, thus the image is displaying with 0px height.

Comment: use pixel instead of percentage

Comment: @Zubairsadiq if I use pixel then it doesn't become responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute position with a proper `z-index`, it could also works :

```
.section {
    background: url("http://i.imgsafe.org/50f3f94.jpeg") no-repeat center/cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqxqw10/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Width and height set the proportions of your div. To set the size of the background, you need the css property `background-size`:

```
.section {
    background-position: 0 0; // start from top left
    background-size: 100% 100%; // expand to 100% in both directions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a certain height to your section e.g :

```
.section {
background: url("http://i.imgsafe.org/50f3f94.jpeg") no-repeat     center/cover;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
```

}

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqxqw10/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Currently .section is null or no data in it
put some data in it or give some specific height to the .section to view section

Answer (score 0):

Add position absolute to the .section class.

```
.section {
   background: url("http://i.imgsafe.org/50f3f94.jpeg") no-repeat center/cover;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%; 
   position absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqxqw10/6/